# What is the ratio of the acceleration in the two cases (a) and (b)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What is the ratio of the acceleration in the two cases (a) and (b)?
[image]

I thought that the ratio would be 1:1 but it my textbook says its 1:3, so can someone explain to me how that's possible.

Comment: Your text book has an error in it.

Comment: @David White: Is it?

Comment: It appears that I wrote too soon.  The drawing on the right indicates that a force of 2mg is only accelerating mass m, not mass 3m.  This is a good problem that I'll try to remember when my students learn Newton's laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ Let's make all the  forces that would be acting on the blocks, in the first case.                 [image]

Now we apply newtons' laws of motion assuming that *block of mass 2m* accelerates **downward** with $a_1$ acceleration and the *block of mass m* accelerates **upward** with same magnitude of $a_1$ acceleration( because they are constrained to have same acceleration till the string is tight).

So,

\begin{align}
&2mg-T=2ma_1\qquad\quad\cdots (1)\\
&T-mg=ma_1\qquad\qquad\cdots (2)\\
\end{align}
adding (1) and (2),
$$\implies(2mg-T)+(T-mg)=2ma_1+ma_1$$
$$\implies mg=3ma_1$$
$$\implies a_1=\frac{g}{3}\qquad\qquad\cdots(3)$$
Thus, acceleration of *block of mass m* would be $\frac{g}{3}$ in upward direction.

$2)$ Now making the forces for the second one:

[image]

We assume that the string is **ideal**, and as we know that an ideal string is *massless* and *inextensible*, which means that the tension at any point through out the string should be constant, because if it is not constant then the net force at *that* point would not be zero and thus the string would have infinite acceleration being massless, therefore the downward force that you apply at the free end of the string should be equal to the tension at that point, which eventually gets transferred to the block and lifts it up.

Thus,
$$|\vec{T}|=|\vec{F}| = 2mg$$

Let's say that the block moves upward with $a_2$ acceleration.

$$T-mg = ma_2$$
$$\implies 2mg - mg = ma_2$$
$$\implies mg = ma_2$$
$$\implies a_2 = g$$

So you see that in this case the *block of mass m* has an upward acceleration equal to $g$, i.e. **3 times the acceleration in first case (refer equation 3)**

Thus $$\frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{\frac{g}{3}}{g} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\implies a_1 : a_2 = 1: 3$$

Comment: +1; Really an amazing explanation:) BTW, what would happen if I took an inextensible & but not massless string? Would the ratio alter? If so, by how much??

Comment: Yes the acceleration would change and would depend on the length of string hanging on respective sides of pulley. You can concentrate these respective **additional** masses as individual blocks hanging on both sides other than $m$ and $2m$, and can consider that these masses are themselves connected to each other by **massless** string and calculate the acceleration as we normally do. But here as the the blocks would accelerate the respective lengths of string hanging on both side would change, which would change the masses of string hanging on both sides and thus acceleration would vary